# Setting Path for Java in Linux

Tags: java, linux, path

I have just installed the latest version of Java Development Kit from Sun Technologies.
I know i have to set the PATH for java

I want to set the path so that it is useful for all the users .

I am using Red HAt Linux 5 .

Comment: Your question in pretty environment-specific. What Linux disto are you using?

Comment: isn't this question for "desktop support" ?

Comment: I am using Linux 5 , in net i found that there is bash_profile file , but i couldn't find any file like that

Comment: (please disregard this comment)

Comment: Red Hat version 5? How did you install the JDK, in general it should be available to all users when following standard OS installation procedures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/java/bin
```