# how to change JVM memory options in redhat linux

Tags: linux

Can anyone help me in changing JVM options in  Red Hat Linux,
how can i know which default JVM options are being used.
let me know the commands please.
how to modify JVM options

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Path for Java in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718955/setting-path-for-java-in-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

The java version currently in use can be decided with `$ java -version`

---

Selecting another installed java version : `# /sbin/alternatives --config java`

---

Getting a new version of java recognized in /etc/**alternatives**/ , example :

`# /sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_66/jre/bin/java 3`

Please replace "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_66/jre/bin/java" with the actual path.

---

Comment: my question is about memory settings like maximum heap, minimum etc.. to change the default values